# How to import Teradata table into HIVE using HUE?

Tags: hive, teradata, hue

I need help importing a Teradata table (with LDAP credentials) into HIVE using HUE interface. I'm new to HIVE and has very little knowledge. Also, the import needs to be a fresh load and not append.

Thank you.

Comment: can you not use sqoop? probably you cant use hue to import table in hive.

Comment: I'm new to it. Can you help with some examples for sqoop?

Answer (score 1):

Ask your admin for access to sqoop.

First of all create  a table `mytable` just like source table.

Use below command when you are using a SQL to extract data. i used oracle as example. for teradata you will get some jdbc driver

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service_name --username xx --password yy --target-dir  'hdfs://your/table1/ --query "select * from scott.mytable where emp_id =1 AND \$CONDITIONS" --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims  --hive-database mydb --hive-table mytable1 --hive-overwrite --delete-target-dir --m 1
```

Use below SQL if you want to extract complete table without any filter.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/service_name --username xx --password yy --target-dir  'hdfs://your/table1/ --hcatalog-database mydb --hcatalog-table mytable1 --table mytable --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims --hive-overwrite --delete-target-dir --m 1
```

Pls note, there can be many options to sqooop, you need to add or remove parameters.